The currentIndex of the carousel is increasing infinitely when I just click the goToNext Button very quickly
What should I do with situation that  the currentIndex of the carousel is increasing infinitely when I just click the goToNext Button very quickly?
I am a rookie learning react now and I just decided to do some projects myself. Now when I tried to make a carousel, I met a problem.
As you can see, here is the origin edition.
what it is supposed to be


and here is the currentIndex I console.log

But if I click very quickly, it becomes like this.

here is the currentIndex

The currentIndex becomes greater and never come back.
Below are my codes.
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import './goodsLunbo.scss';
const GoodsCarousel = ({ items }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(1);
  const itemsWithClones = [items[items.length - 1], ...items, items[0]];
  const [isTransitioning, setIsTransitioning] = useState(true);
  const goToPrevious = () => {
    if(isTransitioning){
      const newIndex = currentIndex - 1;
      setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
    }
  };
  const goToNext = () => {
    if(isTransitioning){
    const newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
    }
    console.log(currentIndex)
  };
  const handleTransitionEnd = () => {
    if (currentIndex === 0) {
      setIsTransitioning(false);
      setCurrentIndex(items.length)
     } else if (currentIndex === items.length + 1) {
      setIsTransitioning(false);
      setCurrentIndex(1);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const transitionTimeout = isTransitioning ? null : setTimeout(() => {
      setIsTransitioning(true);
    }, 5);
    return () => {
      if (transitionTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(transitionTimeout);
      }
    };
  }, [currentIndex]);
  return (
    <div className="goodscarousel">
      <button className="prev" onClick={goToPrevious}>{"<"}</button>
      <div className="goodsItem">
            <div className='goodsContainer'>
            {itemsWithClones.map((it, index) => {
              return it.map((i,ix)=>{
            const key = Object.keys(i)[0];
            const value = i[key];
            return (
            <div key={ix} id={index} className='goods' 
            onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd} 
            style={{ transform: `translateX(-${currentIndex * 387}px)`,transition: isTransitioning?"transform 0.3s ease-in-out":"none"}}>
                {value}
            </div>
            );
           });
          })
          } 
            </div>
      </div>
      <button className="next" onClick={goToNext}>{">"}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GoodsCarousel;

What should I do to fix this problem?

The easiest way to solve this is to use the modulus operation %. Instead of using the handleTransitionEnd function, you can directly program the behavior into your goToNext and goToPrevious functions.
Here is the code:
const goToPrevious = () => {
  if(isTransitioning){
  const newIndex = currentIndex - 1;
  setCurrentIndex(newIndex % items.length); //added mod operation
  }    
};

const goToNext = () => {
  if(isTransitioning){
  const newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
  setCurrentIndex(newIndex % items.length); //added mod operation
  }
};

Alternatively, you can change the behavior of your handleTransitionEnd to reset the values even in the case where they go out of bounds (negatives or greater values than the items.length like so:
const handleTransitionEnd = () => {
  if (currentIndex <= 0) { // less-than or equal-to
    setIsTransitioning(false);
    setCurrentIndex(items.length)
   } else if (currentIndex >= items.length + 1) { // greater-than or equal-to
    setIsTransitioning(false);
    setCurrentIndex(1);
  }
};

